# Arduino Hardlid Unlocker

Tags: esp8266

I am trying to build a unlocker on my hardlid for my ute. I have replaced the manual unlocking mechanism with 2 of these https://www.jaycar.com.au/slave-door-lock-actuator/p/LR8813.

Now my code below works sometimes and I cannot work out why. The way the code should work is

1. Press Unlock Button (Count increments)
2. Press Unlock Button again
3. When count = 2 turn relay on for 4 seconds then turn off
4. reset count to 0
5. If time between presses is longer than 10 seconds reset count to 0

Basic diagram below. Please note the push button is actually wired to a relay which is triggered by the car unlock remote and the LED is the actuators.

[image]

This is my code

```
int switchPin = 2; // choose the input pin (for a pushbutton)
int relayPin = 4; // choose the input pin (for a pushbutton)
int val = 0; // variable for reading the pin status
int counter = 0;
int currentState = 0;
int previousState = 0;
bool lockOn = false;

unsigned long currentMillis = 0;
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;

unsigned long LockcurrentMillis = 0;
unsigned long LockpreviousMillis = 0;


const long interval = 10000;
const long Lockinterval = 4000;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(switchPin, INPUT); // declare pushbutton as input
  pinMode(relayPin, OUTPUT); // declare pushbutton as input


  Serial.println("Ready");
  Serial.print("IP address: ");

}

void loop() {



  currentMillis = millis();
  LockcurrentMillis = millis();
/*
  Serial.print("Current ");
  Serial.print(currentMillis);
  Serial.print(" | Previous ");
  Serial.println(previousMillis);
    //Serial.println(lockOn); 


  Serial.print("Lock Current ");
  Serial.print(LockcurrentMillis);
  Serial.print(" | Lock Previous ");
  Serial.println(LockpreviousMillis);
  */
  if (lockOn == true){

    if (LockcurrentMillis - LockpreviousMillis >= Lockinterval) {
      // save the last time you blinked the LED
      LockpreviousMillis = LockcurrentMillis;
      digitalWrite(relayPin, LOW); // turn relayPin off
      lockOn = false;
      Serial.println("relay off");
    }
  }

  val = digitalRead(switchPin); // read input value
  if (val == HIGH) { // check if the input is HIGH (button released)
    currentState = 1;
  }
  else {
    currentState = 0;
  }
  if (currentState != previousState) {
    if (currentState == 1) {
      counter = counter + 1;
      previousMillis = currentMillis;   //reset timer
      Serial.println(counter);
    }
  }
  if (counter == 2) {
    counter = 0;
    digitalWrite(relayPin, HIGH); // turn relayPin on
    //delay(4000);
    //digitalWrite(relayPin, LOW); // turn relayPin off
    lockOn = true;
          LockpreviousMillis = LockcurrentMillis;

    Serial.println("relay on");
  }

  previousState = currentState;
  //delay(250);
  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
    // save the last time you presse the button
    previousMillis = currentMillis;
    //LockpreviousMillis = LockcurrentMillis;
    //if (counter >= 1) {
    Serial.println("Took too long reset count");
    counter = 0;
    lockOn = false;
    //}
  }
}
```

Any Help would be highly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: First thing: debounce the button.

Comment: Button debounce library: https://github.com/thomasfredericks/Bounce2

Comment: What's a ute?  Have you ever seen the movie "My Cousin Vinnie"?

Comment: @Delta_G, lol .... i was thinking the same thing

Comment: A ute :) ... https://edge.pxcrush.net/std/car/cil/mxu89gdw4v7sjx3evj47ec64d.jpg?width=900

Answer (score 2):

Your circuit drawing seems very wrong, but it is not helpful since, as
you say, it doesn't represent the real circuit. Please, add a proper
diagram of the actual circuit.

As for your reliability problem, I did not dig into the logic of the
code you posted, but I suspect it may be caused by the lack of
[debouncing](https://www.arduino.cc/en/tutorial/debounce). You could add you own debouncing code but, for the sake
of simplicity, I suggest you instead use a ready-made library, like
[Bounce2](https://github.com/thomasfredericks/Bounce2).

For the kind of program you are trying to write, I find that the logic
becomes way easier to grasp if you think think of it as a [finite state
machine](https://majenko.co.uk/blog/finite-state-machine). This is program construct based on the idea that the
system can be in any of a predefined set of possible states, and that
its behavior and the possible state transitions depend on what
particular state it is in. In this specific case, I would use three
states:

- In the `LOCKED` state, the lid is locked and you need to press the
  button twice in order to unlock it. Once you press the button once,
  it transitions to the `WAITING` state.
- In the `WAITING` state, the lid is still locked, but the first
  button press has already been registered. If you press the button
  again, the system transitions to the `UNLOCKED` state. If not,
  after a timeout it transitions back to `LOCKED`.
- In the `UNLOCKED` state the lid is unlocked. After another timeout it
  transitions back to the `LOCKED` state.

Once you have this logic written down, it can be translated into code in
a very straightforward way:

```cpp
#include <Bounce2.h>

const uint8_t  switch_pin = 2;
const uint8_t  relay_pin  = 4;
const uint32_t wait_interval = 10000;  // 10 s
const uint32_t lock_interval =  4000;  //  4 s

Bounce button;

void setup() {
    button.attach(switch_pin, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(relay_pin, OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("Ready.");
}

void loop() {
    static enum { LOCKED, WAITING, UNLOCKED } state = LOCKED;
    static uint32_t last_change;  // not used in the LOCKED state

    button.update();
    uint32_t now = millis();
    switch (state) {
    case LOCKED:
        if (button.fell()) {
            Serial.println(F("Waiting for second button press."));
            state = WAITING;
            last_change = now;
        }
        break;
    case WAITING:
        if (button.fell()) {
            Serial.println(F("Unlocking."));
            digitalWrite(relay_pin, HIGH);
            state = UNLOCKED;
            last_change = now;
        } else if (now - last_change >= wait_interval) {
            Serial.println(F("Wait time out."));
            state = LOCKED;
        }
        break;
    case UNLOCKED:
        if (now - last_change >= lock_interval) {
            Serial.println(F("Locking."));
            digitalWrite(relay_pin, LOW);
            state = LOCKED;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Edgar. You code certainly looks much easier to read and follow. I will try you code now and report back.

Thanks Again

Comment: This works perfectly! I update schematic also. thanks